# Tabbing to a disabled field which becomes enabled

Tags: javascript

How do i move focus to the next field, which, becomes enabled on the blur of the current field.

eg: 2 fields, second one is disabled. When a user tabs from the first field, when blur occurs, the second field enables, I need the focus to move to that field.

```
<input type="text" id="field1">
<input type="text" id="field2" disabled="disabled">

<script>
    $('#field1').blur(function () {
        $('#field2').removeAttr("disabled");
    });
</script>
```

Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/j010knjt/

Answer (score 1):

As per Dutchess'  answer:

Use a `.focus()` but wrap it in a timeout to give the browser time to notice that the second field is not disabled anymore

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j010knjt/3/)

```
$('#field1').keydown(function () {
  $('#field2').removeAttr("disabled");
  setTimeout(function(){$('#field2').focus();});
});
```

Comment: I wish I could +2 just for saying Dutchess (nit picking on the T, don't mind me)

Comment: corrected typo, keep up the work "smuggling" cocaine

Comment: @Andy, I do think you really should use keypress, as this will annoy users when clicking outside of the first input field. Are you doing any form validation before enabling the next field

Comment: This isnt going to achieve the solution required. A timeout needs to be set, which is relying on knowing how long its going to take to complete a field as this method shifts the user to the next field on keydown after the timeout period has elapsed. Its impractical.

Comment: There is validation done on the fields on field entry and also on submission of the form.

Comment: @Andy, if you have form validation why not remove the disabled attr once teh first field is validated? This would ensure the completion. If you include your validation code I can help

Comment: Offtopic: @SterlingArcher, look at the spelling [here](http://archer.wikia.com/wiki/Sterling_Archer)